# Parsing an XML file with Nokigiri (RUBY)

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to pull out some informations from my xml file.

XML:

```
            <CONTENT>
            <dms:ComplexResponse ErrorCode="430" ErrorDescription="null :  PrivacyUE Mancante" Return="false" xmlns:dms="http://dmsmanagerservice">
                <dms:Element Name="DMSVERSION">2.7</dms:Element>
            </dms:ComplexResponse>
        </CONTENT>
```

I need to see the "ErrorCode" and the "ErrorDescription".

This is my code:

```
    require 'nokogiri'

    def see_error(response_xml.xml)


         doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open(response_xml.xml))
         #it shows me the file

         doc.xpath('//dms:ComplexResponse/ErrorCode/ErrorDescription')


    end
```

After that It gives me nothing in return, just an empty array []

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

The namespace needs to be registered:

```
doc.xpath('//dms:ComplexResponse', 'dms' => 'http://dmsmanagerservice').first.attributes['ErrorCode'].value
```

Comment: I have problem with the namespace, how can I remove it?

Comment: I have to deal with namespace but the method you gave me return an error

Comment: You could try `remove_namespaces!` -https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/Nokogiri/XML/Document#remove_namespaces%21-instance_method